# Parsing Date String Treats February as March

Tags: javascript, date

Trying to convert a date-time string from the database (stored local time) and keeping it local instead of being converted to UTC time. The one way I am approaching this is taking the date and splitting the parts and applying the values into a JavaScript date object. For some reason, I give it a date of `2023-02-01` and it thinks its March even when I parse the date value to be an integer and subtract 1.

Like wise:

- `2023-01-01` is January
- `2023-03-01` is March
- `2023-04-01` is April
- and so on...

```js
const dateString = '2023-02-01T09:00:00Z'

const splitDateTime = new Date(dateString)
    .toISOString()
    .split('T'); // ['2023-02-01', '09:00:00']


const dateHalfSplit = splitDateTime[0].split('-'); // ['2023','02','01']
const timeHalfSplit = splitDateTime[1].split(':'); // ['09','00','00']

localDate = new Date();
localDate.setFullYear(parseInt(dateHalfSplit[0]));
localDate.setMonth(parseInt(dateHalfSplit[1]) - 1);
localDate.setDate(parseInt(dateHalfSplit[2]));
localDate.setHours(parseInt(timeHalfSplit[0]));
localDate.setMinutes(parseInt(timeHalfSplit[1]));
localDate.setSeconds(parseInt(timeHalfSplit[2].split('.')[0]));

console.info(localDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
}));

// Output: March 01, 2023 at 9:00 AM
```

Granted, this is not an ideal way to handle dates, from the database backend, but is there something I am missing that somehow this is not handling February correctly or could this be a browser bug?

Comment: The immediate answer is "because today is the 30th" but the real answer is to not really do what you're doing. "*Trying to convert a date-time string from the database (stored local time) and keeping it local instead of being converted to UTC time.*" to keep it local, just feed it into the Date constructor. It will construct the date in your local timezone. So, the bug is from trying to avoid using the proper approach.

Comment: Although "local" only makes sense if the client and server are guaranteed to always talk about the same time zone. If that's not true, then "local" loses its meaning.

Comment: Originally, we just INSERT the dates into the database table directly. We had no frontend and backend to do this properly.

Comment: "*Trying to convert a date-time string from the database (stored local time)*" but '2023-02-01T09:00:00Z' is not local time, it's UTC (and coincides with places that are +0 like GMT). If you want it parsed as local, simply remove the trailing "Z": `new Date('2023-02-01T09:00:00Z'.slice(0,-1))` gives "Wed Feb 01 2023 09:00:00 <local offset> <local timezone name>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Date::setDate` takes into account the local timezone and shifts the month for some reason. Set everyting at once with `Date`'s constructor:

```js
const dateString = '2023-02-01T09:00:00Z'

const splitDateTime = new Date(dateString)
    .toISOString()
    .split('T'); // ['2023-02-01', '09:00:00']

const localDate = new Date(...splitDateTime[0].split('-').map((n, i) => i === 1 ? n - 1: n), ...splitDateTime[1].split(':').map(parseFloat));

console.info(localDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
}));
```

An easier way would be just fix the timezone offset:

```js
const dateString = '2023-02-01T09:00:00Z'

const localDate = new Date(dateString);
localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getTimezoneOffset());

console.info(localDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
}));
```

Comment: "*Calling Date::setDate takes into account the local timezone and shifts the month for some reason.*" that reason is *the current date*. Not the current time zone. If today is the 30th and you switch to a month with 28 days, then it rolls over to the next month. Then changing the day to the 1st just changes to the 1st of the month you rolled over to. Same thing happens if it's the 31st and you switch to a month where the maximum day number is the 30th.

Comment: Also splitting and parsing the already valid timestamp seems like a *huge* overkill. Yes, the solution is to *not* just create a current date and swap fields on it. However, that is way more easily done by feeding the timestamp tot he constructor, without having to chop it up and manipulate it just to get the same result. Same goes for consuming a date with time zone offset then offsetting the offset. A simple removal of the time zone from the string is enough, if it really needs to be local.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for explaining, i've suggested already to use the timestamp string and the timezone removal in the second solution. I don't know why author had chosen more complex one

Comment: The use of *split* is unnecessary as is converting values to number using *pasreFloat* (also, using *Number* is less to type and more semantic). Consider `let localDate = new Date(...dateString.match(/\d+/g).map((v,i) => i == 1? v-1 : v));`.

Comment: @RobG or consider `new Date(dateString)`. And if time zone is not needed, then something like `dateString.split(/Z|\+/)[0]` to clean out either `Z` or an offset like `+01:00`. If it's guaranteed to only be `Z`, then it's as simple as `dateString.slice(0, -1). Again, splitting and chopping up the pieces is a huge overkill, given that the date is already valid for the Date constructor.

Comment: @VLAZ—yep, I was just trying to stick within the intent of the original code which avoids the parser. Certainly just trimming the offset (Z or time) and using the built–in parser is simpler and likely more efficient. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

if I understand correctly you get March instead of February,
you could do it this way

```js
const dateString = '2023-02-01T09:00:00Z';
var localDate = new Date(dateString);
localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getTimezoneOffset());

console.info(localDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
    hour12: true
  
}));
```

Comment: The solution did fixed the month problem, but did not fix the problem where it treated it as a UTC date when the date is suppose to be local.

So it returned the time as 4:00 AM.

Comment: @JeremyTrpka because the `Z` is there. Your initial format that omitted the time zone information would have worked. With that said, it's trivial to strip the time zone, if needed.

Comment: The use of `localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getTimezoneOffset())` assumes that the minutes value will always be "00". It should be `localDate.setMinutes(localDate.getMinutes() - localDate.getTimezoneOffset());` (but trimming the "Z" before parsing obviates the need to shift the time as the timestamp is parsed as local, not UTC).